# Flutter : change bordercolor after validation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textformfield

I want to change the **borderColor** of the `TextFormField` to a green color on successfull validation. **The color should not fade on losing focus though**. Is there something like `successBorder` similar to *error/focusedBorder.*

```
class FormLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  FormLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final _ageController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              validator: validateName,
              controller: _nameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
                labelText: "Name",
                labelStyle:
                    const TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 90, 98, 104)),
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(8),
                  ),
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextFormField(
              validator: validateAge,
              controller: _ageController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
                labelText: "Age",
                labelStyle:
                    const TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 90, 98, 104)),
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(8),
                  ),
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.deepPurple[700]),
                  minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                    const Size.fromHeight(30),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  //createRecord();
                },
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 25),
                  child: Text(
                    "Add",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                )),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

    String? validateName(String? name) {
      if (name == null || name.isEmpty) {
        return "*required";
      } else if (name.length > 10) {
        return "Name should not be longer than 10 characters";
      }
      return null;
    }

    String? validateAge(String? age) {
      if (age == null || age.isEmpty) {
        return "*required";
      } else if (age.length > 3) {
        return "Invalid age";
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Thanks to the answers by [@Timur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72285156/15823478) and [kashif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72285198/15823478)*

Here's what i did to **change the borderColor of the `TextFormField` after validation** :

> 1 - Create a `Stateful widget`

> 2 - Declare varibles for each `TextFormField` to hold the Validation
> state

> 3 - Create a formKey to track the formState and set
> `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction`

> 4 - Use validator to validate `TextFormFields`

> 5 - Use onChanged to update the state of each `TextFormField` by
> validation variables declared earlier

> 6 - Set the border color based on the value of the validation variable

working code:

```
class FormLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FormLayout> createState() => _FormLayoutState();
}

class _FormLayoutState extends State<FormLayout> {
  final _nameController = TextEditingController();

  final _ageController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool _isNameValidated = false;

  bool _isAgeValidated = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              validator: validateName,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _isNameValidated = true;
                });
              },
              controller: _nameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
                labelText: "Name",
                labelStyle:
                    const TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 90, 98, 104)),
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.amber),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(8),
                  ),
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: _isNameValidated ? Colors.green : Colors.amber),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: _isNameValidated ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextFormField(
              validator: validateAge,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _isAgeValidated = true;
                });
              },
              controller: _ageController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
                labelText: "Age",
                labelStyle:
                    const TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 90, 98, 104)),
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(8),
                  ),
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: _isNameValidated ? Colors.green : Colors.amber),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: _isAgeValidated ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.deepPurple[700]),
                  minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                    const Size.fromHeight(30),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  //createRecord();
                },
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 25),
                  child: Text(
                    "Add",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                )),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  //Validator Functions

  String? validateName(String? name) {
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty) {
      return "*required";
    } else if (name.length > 10) {
      return "Name should not be longer than 10 characters";
    }
    return null;
  }

  String? validateAge(String? age) {
    if (age == null || age.isEmpty) {
      return "*required";
    } else if (age.length > 3) {
      return "Invalid age";
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the TextFormField, there is a parameter called `enabledBorder` to display when the InputDecorator is enabled and is not showing an error.

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Resevior Name",
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    enabledBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: I've tried this. but with this the `borderColor` is applied to the `TextFormField` from the start. i'm looking for a way to apply the color only after validation.

Comment: @PixieDust I suggested you to make a variable that holds the value whether it is valid or not. Take look to my example.

Answer (score 0):

create a variables to check whether the TextField is validated or not, then use `enabledBorder:` within `decoration` property of `TextField.`

```
bool _validated = false;
```

After validating a field make the `_validated = true;`

Here's the TextField Code

```
TextFormField(
               validator: validateAge,
                controller: _ageController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
                  labelText: "Age",
                  labelStyle:
                  const TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 90, 98, 104)),
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(8),
                    ),
                  ),
                  errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:  BorderSide(color: _validated? Colors.green :Colors.grey),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),

                ),
              ),
```